# Standard form of hyperbola

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

I've tried to solve this question, but I'm stuck. The question is:

> Find the equation in standard form for the hyperbola centered at $(5,5)$ with one focus at $(-7,5)$ and eccentricity at $\frac{3}{2}$.

When I tried to solve this, I got $a$ to be $2$, $c$ to be $3$, and $b$ to be $5$.

The equation I for was:

$$\frac{(x-5)^2}{4}-\frac{(y-5)^2}{5}=1.$$

However, the numbers don't seem correct.

Any ideas on where I went wrong?

Comment: If $b=5$, then shouldn't it be $(y-5)^2\over 25$?  Or perhaps it should be $(x-5)^2\over 2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The distance from the center $(5,5)$ to the focus $(-7,5)$ is $c$ and equals $12$, Thus $\varepsilon=\frac{3}{2}=\frac{12}{a}$ that implies $a=...\:$. Then $b^2=c^2-a^2=...\:$.